# i18n: t method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my Rails 3.2.2 app I'm trying to use i18n but something is not working correctly.

In fact the "t" method does not work, only "i18n.t" works.

So, for example:

```
t(:login)
=> login
```

Instead:

```
i18n.t(:login)
=> Provide the necessary login info
```

Can you help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Augusto

UPDATE

I used pry to show the source for the t helper and got this:

From: /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb @ line 46:
Number of lines: 16
Owner: ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
Visibility: public

```
    def translate(key, options = {})
      options.merge!(:rescue_format => :html) unless options.key?(:rescue_format)
      if html_safe_translation_key?(key)
        html_safe_options = options.dup
        options.except(*I18n::RESERVED_KEYS).each do |name, value|
          unless name == :count && value.is_a?(Numeric)
            html_safe_options[name] = ERB::Util.html_escape(value.to_s)
          end
        end
        translation = I18n.translate(scope_key_by_partial(key), html_safe_options)

        translation.respond_to?(:html_safe) ? translation.html_safe : translation
      else
        I18n.translate(scope_key_by_partial(key), options)
      end
    end

3] pry(main)> show-source helper.t

From: /Users/phishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb @ line 46:
Number of lines: 16
Owner: ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
Visibility: public

def translate(key, options = {})
  options.merge!(:rescue_format => :html) unless options.key?(:rescue_format)
  if html_safe_translation_key?(key)
    html_safe_options = options.dup
    options.except(*I18n::RESERVED_KEYS).each do |name, value|
      unless name == :count && value.is_a?(Numeric)
        html_safe_options[name] = ERB::Util.html_escape(value.to_s)
      end
    end
    translation = I18n.translate(scope_key_by_partial(key), html_safe_options)

    translation.respond_to?(:html_safe) ? translation.html_safe : translation
  else
    I18n.translate(scope_key_by_partial(key), options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the `t` method is a helper and therefore only available in views and controllers.

If you try to use I18n from models or the rails console, you should use `I18n.t`

Comment: I'm trying to use it in my application.html.erb layout file.  It is a view, so it should work...

Comment: Does `translate(:login)` work? DO you use any monkey patch in your app? Looks like you broke the `t` helper

Comment: translate(:login) does work.  I don't think I'm using any strange thing inside my application...How can I know this?

Comment: You'd know if you added some monkey patches to your app (unless you're not the only one to work on it). The `t` method is just an alias to `translate`. Try to search in your project for `def t`, maybe you overwrote the method in one of your helpers?

Comment: If you're still stuck : install the `pry-rails` gem (add it to the Gemfile, and bundle install. Then fire-up a rails console. The prompt should say pry(main)>. From there, do `include ActionView::Helpers` and then give me the output of `show-source t`

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I just followed your instructions and posted the result as an update to my question.

Comment: What does `helper.t(:login)` return?

Comment: helper.t(:login) works perfectly: => "Provide the necessary login info"

Comment: So there must be something in your app overwriting the `t` helper somehow. Could be a gem or anything really ... search for `def t` through the project (with 'whole words' option), then if you don't find anything, try to remove a maximum of gems and try again ...